# Is there a way I can disable part of my display that has a green line?

Tags: broken-screen, google-pixel

I have a Pixel 3, and I picked up my phone after momentarily charging it on a wireless pad (for about 30 minutes) this morning, as I usually do, and now it has a green line near the right edge of the screen.

Seeing as it is a display issue, I will probably need to get it replaced.

In the meantime, though, logistics make this difficult, and I would much rather have a black streak on the side than a green one.

Is there any way I can get the phone to just disable a vertical line of pixels?

The touch aspect of the screen works fine, so I don't want to modify that.

Comment: There are a number of questions already on this site about this issue. Have you read them, and can point out where the answers supplied previously do not apply, or fail for some reason in your case? You can start to solve this by clicking through the 'broken-screen' tag you have attached to your post and exploring the solutions previous.

Comment: As far as this site goes, I can't really find another question with the tag about the green/pink lines others have reported. I've tried restarting my phone in safe mode, but the line appears whenever the display turns on, even slightly.

Comment: I've seen some articles about Samsung's AMOLED, and how some programs/apps can disable pixels for that screen type, but my model uses OLED.

Comment: Most of the solutions I've found involve replacing the screen, but since I can't do that for logistical reasons right now, disabling the individual pixels themselves seems like it would be a straightforward way to reduce the visual impact.